# How do I dump all of the bytes java writes to a network?

Tags: java

I'm aware of the system property `-Djavax.net.debug=all` that can be used to write the data java sends over the network into plain text on the console. I'm also aware of tools such as wireshark and tcpdump that can dump that can monitor the network and dump the traffic going out.

I'm running into a peculiar issue and what I'm interested in learning is what java 'thinks' it's sending over the wire vs what's actually being sent over the wire. So wireshark and tcpdump are not a good fit since they are too late in the stack. Is there another java system property that works similar to javax.net.debug, but dumps out unencrypted network communications?

Comment: Why you need this? I mean if javax.net.debug is giving the data which is needed for debugging purpose that's why it is there. I feel you should tell what issue you are facing.

Comment: Why do you think there's a difference between what Java "thinks" it's sending vs. what's actually sent?

Comment: If you need to inspect the packet, take a look at this tool: https://www.wireshark.org/

Comment: @Amogh, It seems like javax.net.debug is giving out only SSL data. I want the plain text data.

Comment: @Kayaman Because of some wonky behavior I'm noticing. A simple explanation is that I'm trying to send content to a web service. The input stream I'm reading looks right, but the content I'm sending looks wrong (one of the chunks is in the wrong place). I was able to observe this using wireshark. Furthermore, this only happens in Windows. If I can observe that Java thinks its sending the chunks in the right order then I can narrow down the issue to likely be the OS.

Comment: Hi @Lorien, I mentioned in my question that I'm aware of wireshark. And in fact, that's where I confirmed that the bytes over the wire are being sent wrong. I'm more interested in what Java thinks its sending over the wire so I can compare that to what is being sent over the wire.

Comment: @JasonThompson oh! so you mean you want to observe data (plain data) sent over non-SSL connection. am I right?

Comment: @Amogh Right. But I want to see what Java thinks its sending. Wireshark proves that the data is wrong, but all of my debugging shows that the inputstream I'm using as the source is correct. It's strange as the HTTP chunks will appear out of order 20% of the time.

On linux, the data is always right.

Comment: @JasonThompson sounds really very strange. I have never observed this (especially with wireshark/tcpdump), but what I suggest is if you are just observing data/chunk by wireshark/tcpdump then you should check at listening side (may be create a dummy listener) which will takes byte from network and then logging into a file/console by converting into string. May be this could be a kind off debugging

Comment: Check this https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/193745/udp-order-of-packets-with-direct-connection and https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2634907/tcp-ip-packets-that-are-received-out-of-sequence-are-discarded-in-wind

Comment: @Amogh Thanks for the links. Unfortunately, they're not quite the same as what I'm trying to figure out. I'm using TCP rather than UDP. Also, it's not the packets that are out of order, but the chunks.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/152869/discussion-between-amogh-and-jason-thompson).